# GCC warning "dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules"

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I use a `QueryInterface`function that will return a pointer on a given interface based on an IID.

```
DecodingFramework::IVariableFramerate* pInt = NULL;
DecodingFramework::DecodeResult iVFR = pVideoDescription->QueryInterface(IID_IVariableFramerate, (void**)(&pInt));
if(pInt != NULL && iVFR == DF_SUCCESS)
{
    //use the IVariableFramerate interface using pInt
}
```

But in that code `(void**)(&pInt)` produce an error with message `dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules`

I updated the code to the following :

```
void* pInt = NULL;
DecodingFramework::DecodeResult iVFR = pVideoDescription->QueryInterface(IID_IVariableFramerate, &pInt);
if(pInt != NULL && iVFR == DF_SUCCESS)
{
    DecodingFramework::IVariableFramerate* pVideoVFR = reinterpret_cast<DecodingFramework::IVariableFramerate*>(pInt);

    //use the IVariableFramerate interface using pVideoVFR
}
```

I found a lot of question related to that warning message but it was mainly when casting more complex data than just the address pointer on something to a `void**` ?
Is there a problem for real ? I don't understand the rational behind that warning.

Comment: May be helpful, a good article on strict aliasing [Type-punning and strict-aliasing](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/) and this is a more detailed one but will take a bit longer to digest [Understanding Strict Aliasing](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html).

Comment: Have you read the many other questions (and answers) with the same exact warning message in their title?

Comment: When `QueryInterface` assigns a value to `pInt`, what type does the lvalue it uses have? If that lvalue is not compatible with `DecodingFramework::IVariableFramerate *`, then your updated code still violates aliasing rules.

Comment: You don't need a `reinterpret_cast` there, `static_cast` is fine. Don't use `reinterpret_cast` unless you **really** need to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's why lying to the compiler about the pointer type is bad:

```
struct SomeClass { int a; };
SomeClass* global_pointer;

void open_object( void** result, int x )
{
    cout << global_pointer->a;
    *result = new SomeClass{x};
    cout << global_pointer->a;
}
```

The compiler is perfectly allowed to replace that by:

```
auto temp = global_pointer->a;
cout << temp;
*result = new SomeClass{x}; // according to the Standard, the compiler is allowed to assume this line CANNOT change global_pointer, because the type is wrong
cout << temp;
```

If you then call

```
open_object((void**)&global_pointer);
```

then you may be surprised by the result.